# how to set text to one array element of text fields on click

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, mouselistener

I cant get the Mouse listener to set text to the text fields 
but I can get the colour.

I need both but i cant figure out how to do it.

The buttons set the text and colour that will be displayed when a text box is clicked

e.g. When you click on the button it will set the background to Blue and add text "Chair" for the component clicked.

Thank you for any assistance.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import static javafx.scene.paint.Color.color;

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == btnBlue) {
        temp = Color.BLUE;
        tempString = "Chair";
    }
}

private void displayTextFields(SpringLayout layout, MouseListener listener) {
    // txtX = LocateAJTextField(this,null,layout,2,650,30);
    // txtY = LocateAJTextField(this,null,layout,2,680,30);
    for (int y = 0; y < totalY; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < totalX; x++) {
            int xPos = x * 26 + 200;
            int yPos = y * 20 + 100;
            fields[x][y] = LocateAJTextField(this, this, layout, 2, xPos, yPos);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question edited for more readble code and format, updated answer so please let me know if you have any more questions

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not changing the text in Button but assign it to a variable only,
try to use the following function given to replace that line:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == btnBlue) {
        temp = Color.BLUE;
        e.getSource().setText("Chair");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on that im not good with java so im not sure what your saying

Comment: You are having a JButton as far as i guess, so you want to set the button text to "Chair" for example, i will edit the answer for you for more detail

Comment: ahh i see but unfortunately .setText doesnt work so i think im missing the import

Comment: haha, as far as i know, you should have declared the button elsewhere, you can replace that e.getSource() to the button variable, i guess that will work too

Comment: and also that changes the text of the button not the text field needs to change the text box from the Fields array using JTextBox

Comment: The idea will be similar, when you clicked, verified the btn, then do somelogic on the J Object you wanted to do

Comment: Yes and thats what i dont know how to do

Comment: identify your JTextField by id or some specific properties you given, and then use the setText or other function to do the logic you want

Comment: well i still cant manage to do it so im still doing something wrong i guess
if(e.getSource()==btnBlue)
      {
        temp=Color.BLUE;
        tempString = "Chair";
         
      }
e.getComponent().setName(tempString);

but setName doesnt do what i want and i cant use setText there

Comment: first of all, identify the what is the data type of e.getSource(), you can print if out by e.getSource().getClass().getName() -> this is to ensure the stuff we are working with is what we really want. 

Second, filter the condition by checking if that is btnBlue as you stated above, then no need to use e.getSource() anymore because you can access btnBlue there right? try to use btnBlue.setText(), i guess that will be fine

Comment: if you are still struggling, please post the error message or what really happened when you tried to click

Comment: I dont want to change the text of the button i want to change the text of the text fields the 2d array creates on click i dont want to change all of them just the one i click hence needing to use getcomponent so doing btnBlue.setText() wont work cause that just changes the button